# How can i create list of datatype of an existing object in java

Tags: java, generics, object, types

Well the question says it all. Heres an Example of what i want

```
String s = new String();
List<s.type> ls = new ArrayList<s.type>();
```

Something like that, or any elegant way to achieve this, please no multiple if conditions or condition logic, as there may be unlimited data types, i have used string here only as an example, it can be anything.

Comment: Ok someone actually gave a very close answer and now deleted the answer :/ those awkward moments.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to know the class (*type*) of an instance (*object*) in runtime (*existing*), which has nothing to do with generics though, as Petr explained.

```
public class Types {    
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s = "";
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Types t = new Types();

     List<Class> types = new LinkedList<Class>();         
     types.add(Integer.class);
     types.add(t.getClass());
     types.add(r.getClass());
     types.add(s.getClass());

     for (Class type :types) {
         System.out.println(type.getSimpleName());
     }         
 }    
}
```

which outputs:

```
Integer
Types
Runtime
String
```

However, such approach is rarely needed, so rethink is there a simpler solution to your problem. If you still want to tackle it like this:

- [What is reflection, and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)
- [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

EDIT:

The other interpretation of your question leads to a dynamic generic list as answer:

```
public static <T> List<T> createListOfType() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> a = createListOfType();    
    List<Integer> b = createListOfType();
    a.add("");
    b.add(2);
    a.add(2); // remove this line to compile
    b.add(""); // remove this line to compile       
}
```

Comment: This was useful for another part of my application, improved the elegance and scalability, thank you for that. but not the solution for my question.

Comment: Ah the other implementations close to what im looking for Thanks.

Comment: In both of those methods, `type` is not used, and should be removed.

Comment: If you are the one " someone actually gave a very close answer and now deleted the answer" I do apologize for stealing the answer, but I wanted to help OP. Leave the downvote though :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the runtime type of s and use it in a generic, this is impossible. Generics in Java are used only in compile time for type-checking and type inference. The generic's information is erased in the runtime, so the runtime can't tell the differense between `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`.

If you just want to make a generic with the compile-time-known type for s, than it does not make sense, because you already know the type of s and you can write a class name for it.